# arithmetic problem

Tags: java, geometry

I have written this code but it doesn't compute `((((bY - aY) / (maxX - minX)) * (p.getX() - minX)) + aY)`  for me.please help me.

a part of code :(I have four points which aY means the "y" of point "a")

```
        int aY = minXY[0]; 
        int bY = maxXY[0];
        int cY = minXY[minXY.length - 1];
        int dY = maxXY[maxXY.length - 1];

    for (Point p : pointList) {
            if ((p.getY() > ((((bY - aY) / (maxX - minX)) * (p.getX() - minX)) + aY)) && (p.getY() < ((((dY - cY) / (maxX - minX)) * (p.getX() - minX)) + cY))) {

                list.add(p);

            } else if (p.getY() < ((((bY - aY) / (maxX - minX)) * (p.getX() - minX)) + aY)) {
                upperHull.add(p);
                int m = ((((bY - aY) / (maxX - minX)) * (p.getX() - minX)) + aY);
                System.out.println(m);


            } else if (p.getY() > ((((dY - cY) / (maxX - minX)) * (p.getX() - minX)) + cY)) {
                lowerHull.add(p);

            }



        }
```

the output will be an integer which is the `"y" of point "a".`
totally ,my specific arithmetic statement doesn't work.please help me why?also I have checked each value in the arithmetic statement and they are OK but can not compute the result for me.
specific arithmetic statement : `((((bY - aY) / (maxX - minX)) * (p.getX() - minX)) + aY)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be more helpful if you explained what result you are getting and what you don't like about it.  "can not compute the result" implies you are getting an exception of some kind, but I don't think that's what you mean.

What you probably mean is that the result it is getting is not what you expect, and the most likely reason for this is that all your variables are `int` so it is doing integer arithmetic, but you probably want to get floating-point results from your divisions.

I suggest changing your local variables to `float` or `double`, so the ints will be automatically converted before doing the arithmetic.

Also, it looks like you have two complex arithmetic expressions in there multiple times.  I would calculate them once and assign them to local variables (within the loop, before the if).

Comment: "...and the most likely reason for this is that all your variables are int so it is doing integer arithmetic, but you probably want to get floating-point results from your divisions..." - exactly so.  +1

Comment: +1.  An even better reason (than efficiency) for extracting local variables is clarity.  It's very hard to see what you're trying to do; calculating terms like deltaX and xRange would begin to clarify it.

Comment: OOps I did it really it works,but now I get the importance of data type.thanks a lot.